# Tooltip over DataGrid row in C# .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, tooltip

I want to add tooltip for every row (and for every cell) in DataGrid. How can I do this? I've tried RowDataBound and CellFormating, but it seems that I can't use this examples in my code (no similar events)

Do you have any ideas how to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is an Example From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tooltiptext(v=vs.110).aspx), In which they Clearly described how to Gets or sets the ToolTip text associated with this cell. with the help of `_CellFormatting` event of the control; Consider the code below:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["column_name"].Index)  && e.Value != null)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        cell.ToolTipText = "This is given ToolTip";
    }
}
```

You can try Conditional Tooltips Too like this(this too explained in the associated link):

```
if (e.Value.Equals("some value"))
{
    cell.ToolTipText = "ToolTip 1";
}
else if (e.Value.Equals("some other value"))
{
    cell.ToolTipText = "ToolTip 2";
}
// Like wise
```